# Printing output from grep in bash script yields broken string

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have the following simple bash script that stores the output of a command in a variable and prints it:

```
size=$(curl -sI "http://speedtest.reliableservers.com/1GBtest.bin" | grep -i "length")

echo "--> ${size} <--"
```

When running the command in the terminal, I get the following output:

```
Content-Length: 1073471824
```

But when I run this bash script that invokes the command, I get the following output:

```
 <--Content-Length: 1073741824
```

What is going on?

Comment: @Kenney Could this be a terminal encoding problem?

Comment: I run it as `./wtf.sh` in the Ubuntu terminal. Both `sh wtf.sh` and `bash wtf.sh` result in the same thing.

Comment: @Kenney Both result in "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" for me. Vim shows that `2.txt` has just a single line, however.

Comment: `grep -i "length.*[0-9]"` or use `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the HTTP response header ends with `CRLF` or `\r\n`. The `$(..)` does strip the `\n` but not the `\r`, so that the output will be

```
--> 1073741824\r <--
```

where the `\r` carriage return sets the cursor to the start of the line, overwriting `-->` with `<--`.

You can strip the `\r` with `sed`:

```
size=$(curl -sI "http://speedtest.reliableservers.com/1GBtest.bin" | grep -i "length" \
     | sed -e 's/\r//' )

echo "--> ${size} <--"
```

Comment: That solves the problem, thanks. Is there no cleaner way to get the result than stripping the \r like this?

Comment: Cleaner how?  There are certainly other ways to strip it; `tr -d '\015'` comes immediately to mind.

Comment: @tripleee I was thinking of some flag that forces cURL to output unix line endings.

Comment: I don't think there is one, but `grep -io '^content-length: [0-9]*'` would not capture and thus not print the carriage return in the first place.

Comment: @Overv Depending on what you actually need, the `--write-out` option may be useful.